# How display measure with null Value as 'N/A' in excel (SSAS)

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssas

I create Measure on SSAS Cube ,i already make formatString on Measure  = #,##0;-#,##0;N/A;
[image]

i see on cube is good result

[image]

But when i get the result on excel the value became 0 
[image]

Please help me. where do i was wrong.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a pivottable of the results and the field that contains the N/A is in the value area. The value area works with agregates and so cant give you much else then a number (or percentage etc.) As far as I know excel won't allow the formatting you are trying to make in a pivottable value field.

If you absolutly need this exact formatting try the ssrs report builder, it has a lot more bells and whistles.